# Directory.Move(): Access to Path is Denied

Tags: c#, exception, directory, access-denied

I'm writing this Windows Form Application in Visual Studio 2010 using C#.

There is a Execute button on the form, the user will hit the button, the program will generate some files and are stored in the `Output` folder (which is created by the program using `Directory.CreateDirectory()`)

I want to create an Archive folder to save the output files from previous runs.

In the beginning of each run, I try to move the existing `Output` folder to the `Archive` folder, then create a new `Output` folder. Below is the function I ran to move directory.

```
static void moveToArchive()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("Archive")) Directory.CreateDirectory("Archive");
    string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmms");
    try
    {
        Directory.Move("Output", "Archive\\" + timestamp);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can not move folder: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem I ran into confuses me a lot...

There are some times that I can successfully move the Output folder to archive, but sometimes it fails.

The error message I got from catching the exception is `Access to path 'Output' is denied.`

I have checked that all the files in the `Output` folder are not in use. I don't understand how access is denied sometimes and not all the times.

Can someone explain to me and show me how to resolve the problem?

**--Edit--**

After HansPassant comment, I modified the function a little to get the current directory and use the full path. However, I'm still having the same issue.

The function now looks like this:

```
static void moveToArchive()
{
    string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    Console.WriteLine("Current Directory = " + currentDir);
    if (!Directory.Exists(currentDir + "\\Archive")) Directory.CreateDirectory(currentDir + "\\Archive");
    string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmms");
    try
    {
        Directory.Move(currentDir + "\\Output", currentDir + "\\Archive\\" + timestamp);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can not move folder: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

I printed out the current directory and it is just as what I was expecting, and I'm still having trouble using full path. `Access to path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\FormApp\Output' is denied.`

**--Edit--**

Thank you everyone for answering and commenting.

I think some of you miss this part so I'm going stress it a bit more.

**The Directory.Move() sometimes work and sometimes fails.**

When the function succeed, there was no problem. `Output` folder is moved to `Archive`

When the function fails, the exception message I got was *Access to path denied.*

Comment: Make sure that there is a "Output" folder and that there is no file named "Output" (without file extension) in the parent directory

Comment: @jgauffin the Output folder does exist and none of the files within it are named Output. When the moveToArchive() fails, the newly generated output files were created in the Outuput folder overwriting the files generated from previous runs.

Comment: This code critically depends on Environment.CurrentDirectory being set correctly.  That goes wrong all the time, it is the worst possible global variable.  Always use full path names, like c:\foo\bar\baz.  And *never* rely on being able to write to c:\program files, UAC puts a stop to that.

Comment: @HansPassant The program is basically a executable, put in a folder, along with other files needed to run the app (2 dlls and some input files) I want to give the user the whole folder, so when the user run the exe, all output files will be in the same folder (to make it organized and easy for user), that is why I'm using relative path instead of full path.

Comment: Then the CurrentDirectory is still dependent on how you started your programm. The folder where the programm resides is not automatically the currentDirectory.

Comment: @Tony antivirus and firewall are both off and the problem still exist.

Comment: @sora0419 have you tried accessign your folderlocations on startup like so `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` then editing the string you get to match the folder dir you need?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle like mentioned in my edit, I uses Environment.CurrentDirectory to get full path, I printed out the full path and it is correct, but access still denies.

Comment: Is there a file in the directory with an open handle somewhere? Are you logging into this directory or someone else, etc.?  MSOffice may have locked a file. Any files in there with ReadOnly attributes? One of the .DLLs could be loaded into a running program.

Comment: Do you have the folder open in an explorer window or in a command prompt window?

Comment: I'd guess that the code that generates the files does not close them properly. It might work sometimes because the GC collected & finalized the dangling file handles already. The code that writes the files might be of interest in this case.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I'm pretty sure that all files are closed because I'm using 'using' to generate files. I'll double check and see if I miss anything. Thanks a lot for trying to help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you all for the replies and help. I have figured out what the issue was.

It is because there was a file that's not completely closed.

I was checking the files that were generated, and missed the files the program was reading from.

All files that were generated were closed completely. It was one file I used `StreamReader` to open but didn't close. I modified the code and am now not having problem, so I figure that's were the issue was.

Thanks for all the comments and answers, that definitely help me with thinking and figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

See http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm

Sometimes, you try to move or delete a file or folder and receive access violation or file in use - errors. To successfully delete a file, you will need to identify the process which has locked the file. You need to exit the process first and then delete the particular file. To know which process has locked a file, you may use one of the methods discussed in this article.

Using Process Explorer - download from  http://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip

Process Explorer shows you information about which handles and DLLs processes have opened or loaded.

Download Process Explorer from Microsoft site and run the program.
Click the Find menu, and choose Find Handle or DLL...
Type the file name (name of the file which is locked by some process.)
After typing the search phrase, click the Search button
You should see the list of applications which are accessing the file.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped on the same problem recently. Using PE I'd figured that only process using that particular directory was explorer.exe. I'd opened few windows with explorer, one pointing to parent directory of one that I was about to move.

It appeared, that after I visited that sub-folder and then returned (even to root level!) the handle was still being kept by explorer, so C# was not able to modify it in any way (changing flags, attributes etc.).

I had to kill that explorer window in order to made C# operate properly.

Comment: I had the same issue with windows explorer. pretty ridiculous to think that simply looking at a directory causes access denied.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.SetAttributes(Application.dataPath + "/script", FileAttributes.Normal);
Directory.Move(Application.dataPath + "/script", Application.dataPath + "/../script");
```

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
If this does not solve, maybe check/change the antivirus, or the some other program is locking some file in or the folder.

```
    static object moveLocker = new object();
    static void moveToArchive()
    {
        lock (moveLocker)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  // Give sometime to ensure all file are closed.

            //Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string applicationPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string archiveBaseDirectoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(applicationPath, "Archive");

            if (!Directory.Exists(archiveBaseDirectoryPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveBaseDirectoryPath);

            String timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmms");
            String outputDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Output");
            String destinationTS = System.IO.Path.Combine(archiveBaseDirectoryPath, timestamp);
            try
            {
                Directory.Move(outputDirectory, destinationTS);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not move folder " + outputDirectory + " to: " + destinationTS + "\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, when I copy your function over, the Output folder is not moved to the Archive at all.

Comment: I just tried it again and it's still not moving at all. My function sometimes work and sometimes doesn't, I use your function and its not doing the move at all. I also tried putting your lock method into my function and that doesn't help either.

Comment: I changed again. I think that now it will work. Please try and tell me. I understood: from CurrentDirectory to Application Directory/Archive/TimeStamp  . If it does not work, if safe, disable antivirus? please paste here the Output error message.

Comment: Try it on another computer.

Comment: Thank you so much for following up and helping. With your function, I still couldn't get the program to move the directory. The program didn't break because the function is using try-catch. The message printed on the console is as below. "Can not move folder C:\Users\Me\Desktop\FormApp\Output to: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\FormApp\Archive\201309211714" and on a separate line "Access to path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\FormApp\Output' is denied."

Comment: Sorry that I miss mentioning this. Your function have the same issue as mine. Sometime the move is successful and sometime it's not.

Comment: I think that the problem is the other program that writes to that Output. Is it closing the file handlers? Is the file\folder still open by some other program? Maybe a delay before starting moving will help.

Comment: When the program gives this error message, try to move the folder using Windows Explorer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005924/access-to-the-path-is-denied

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it failed sometimes but not all the time. I thought I'd wrap it in a Try Catch block and present the user with an Access Denied message and once I wrapped it in the Try Catch block it stopped failing. I can't explain why.

```
 If existingFile.FileName <> newFileName Then
    Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(existingFile.FilePath)
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dir.FullName)
    newFileName = path & "\" & newFileName

    File.SetAttributes(existingFile.FilePath, FileAttributes.Normal)
        Try
            IO.File.Move(existingFile.FilePath, newFileName)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
End If
```

Comment: The Try Catch block is used to manage the exception programmatically, so it is no more presented to the user. It doesn't mean the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Prevent further execution within the catch to determine if it 'actually' fixed the issue. Though as Fil says, chances are, you've just not been presented with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Renamed many directories in a loop when following the certain template. From time to time the program crashed on different directories. It helped to add a **sleep thread** before Directory.Move. I need to create some delay.
But it slows down the copying process.

```
foreach (var currentFullDirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(startTargetFullDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                var shortCurrentFolderName = new DirectoryInfo(currentFullDirPath).Name.ToLower();
                if (shortCurrentFolderName.Contains(shortSourceDirectoryName))
                {
                    // Add Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    var newFullDirName = ...;
                    Directory.Move(currentFullDirPath, newFullDirName);
                }
            }
```