# How to close a file after creating it

Tags: c#

I am coding in C# for the first time and encountering this.

I use the function `File.WriteAllBytes(OutputFileName, dest);` which is creating a file on the disk and when my application tries to open the same file using `file.Open` giving me an exception **Access to Path Denied**. Please help me to get rid of this. I am on Windows 7, not running as administrator.

Thank you.

Comment: This probably happens because you don't have permissions to write on that folder. Try to change the path.

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005924/access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Comment: @dburner : The file is getting created. If there is no permission, I think the file will not be created.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, I am doing it correctly at the code level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is closed. It is denied for other reasons. Check the path, or maybe you could open it with  FileMode `File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)`. Otherwise check your permissions.

> Given a byte array and a file path, this method opens the specified file, writes the contents of the byte array to the file, **and then closes the file**.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I use File.Open(File1Path, FileMode.Open); to try opening the file

Answer (score 1):

The method `WriteAllBytes` closes the file after writing the byte array to the file so I guess your problem lies elsewhere.

### Definition:

> Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

More reading on the method: [**File.WriteAllBytes Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Robert was ahead of me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things spring to mind:

1. Where are you saving the file to? Windows 7 seems to picky about saving to the root of C:\ these days.
2. Permissions issue.

Comment: True, cant create a file on C:. Causing exception.